# Modify object containing array based on an array which contains an object

Tags: javascript

Here are the variables:

```js
let linked = {
  related: [
    [0, 'a', 'b'],
    [0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    [0, "s"],
    [0, 'd'],
    [0, 'g', 'n', 'h']
  ]
}

let hold = [{
    0: 4, // 0 represents [0,'a','b']
    1: 3 // 1 represents [0,'c','d','e','f','g']
  },
  {
    3: 2, // 3 represents [0,'d']
    4: 6 //  4 represents [0,'g','n', 'h'] 
  } 
];
```

The `hold array` contains two objects and each object's property represents index of `link.related` .

The problem is I want to add values of each `hold object` property to the first element of `linked.related`.

So the result should be:

```js
let linked = {
  related: [
    [4, 'a', 'b'],
    [3, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    [0, "s"],
    [2, 'd'],
    [6, 'g', 'n', 'h']
  ]
}
```

So I want to **sum** values of `hold` with the first element of `linked.related`

Comment: please add the *...* part. what is meaning of the second property of the objects?

Comment: Sorry... ok....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 forEach loops

```
hold.forEach(x => {
  Object.keys(x).forEach (y => {
    linked.related[y][0] += x[y]
  });
});
```

```js
let linked = {
  related: [

    [0, 'a', 'b'],
    [0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    [0, "s"],
    [0, 'd'],
    [0, 'g', 'n', 'h']

  ]
}


let hold = [{
    0: 4,
    1: 3
  },
  {
    3: 2,
    4: 6
  } 
];
hold.forEach(x => {
  Object.keys(x).forEach (y => {
    linked.related[y][0] += x[y]
  });
});
console.log(linked.related);
```

Comment: I think a misunderstanding happend .. I want to sum them not just add them ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` and `Object.entries`

```js
let linked = {related: [[0, 'a', 'b'],[0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],[0, "s"],[0, 'd'],[0, 'g', 'n', 'h']]}
let hold =[{0: 4, 1:3},{3: 2, 4:6}]

hold.forEach(v => {
  Object.entries(v).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    linked.related[k][0] += v
  })
})

console.log(linked)
```

Comment: I think a misunderstanding happend .. I want to sum them not just add them ...

Comment: @SaraRee it's not mentioned anywhere in question, can you update your question accordingly ? and post the desired output as well, if you want to add them changing `=` to `+=` will solve

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate hold and get the entries for the update.

```js
var linked = { related: [[0, 'a', 'b'], [0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], [0, "s"], [0, 'd'], [0, 'g', 'n', 'h']] },
    hold = [{ 0: 4, 1: 3 }, { 3: 2, 4: 6 }];

hold.forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([i, v]) => linked.related[i][0] += v));

console.log(linked);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think a misunderstanding happend .. I want to sum them not just add them ...